# Laravel API is receiving string between quotes written "null" instead of a null field

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, laravel-5.6, form-data

I am building a form with `FormData` for sending a file along with other information to a Laravel API, but the file might be `null`, according to the rule:

```
$validator = Validator::make(Request::all(), [
    ...
    "file" => "nullable|mimes:pdf,doc,docx"
]);
```

And from the front-end, the `FormData` being sent:

```
const data = new FormData();

data.append("name", name);
data.append("instructions", instructions);
data.append("reward", reward);
data.append("deadline", deadline);
data.append("file", file ? file[0] : null);
```

`file` has a default value of `null`, but when I check the logs of `Request::all()`, I see the following:

```
[2018-08-18 06:55:13] local.INFO: array (
  ..
  'file' => 'null',
)
```

Comment: Since you are saying file might be null so what you can do is return file instead of null when it is null. Something like data.append("file", file ? file[0] : file); is this wt u are looking for?

Comment: I have updated my answer kindly check it out

Comment: [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) requires the 2nd parameter to be a string or a blob which means that it is very likely it is coerced to a string if it's not a string. The string value of `null` is `"null"`

Comment: Rather than a nullable file value, just don't append file to formData if there isn't one. In the validator, make the file parameter optional, rather than nullable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file looks like an array so what you can do is check if it is an array if yes then assign file[0] otherwise assign file

```
const data = new FormData();
let fileData = file;
if(Array.isArray(file)){
    fileData = file[0]; 
}else{
    fileData = file
}
data.append("name", name);
data.append("instructions", instructions);
data.append("reward", reward);
data.append("deadline", deadline);
data.append("file", fileData);
```

OR

```
data.append("name", name);
data.append("instructions", instructions);
data.append("reward", reward);
data.append("deadline", deadline);
data.append("file", Array.isArray(file) ? file[0] : file);
```

Comment: No, it is set as `null`. If I do it like this, it will throw an error saying it cannot read property 'length' of null.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `typeof` to check whether the file is `object` or not before appending it into the `formData` object.

> I would suggest you to loop through the passing values because it makes the code more compact and allows to add `n` number of input values.

```
 let formData = new FormData();
  for(var key in userData){
   if(key == "file" && typeof userData['file'] == "object"){
     formData.append(key, userData[key][0]);
   }
    formData.append(key, userData[key]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a `null` to your form data just add data conditionally:

```
const data = new FormData();

data.append("name", name);
data.append("instructions", instructions);
data.append("reward", reward);
data.append("deadline", deadline);
if (Array.isArray(file) && file.length > 0) {
    data.append("file", file[0]);
}
```

Your validation already treats the `file` field as optional so the back-end should deal with it just fine.